# Issue with routing and link using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, next.js

I am facing an issue with routing and links in Nextjs. I have created a blog like page using React+Typescript and I would like to use the same code in Nextjs. I was initially using `import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';` .However since this link doesn't work with Nextjs,  I have used the link/next import.

The issue is when, I try to click on "Aboutus" of my Navbar, I get the following error:

> 404
>   This page could not be found.

Here is the code of my Navbar.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
const Navbarr : React.FC = () => {
return (
<div>
<AppName >
        <Link href="/"><a>Abc</a></Link>
    </AppName>
    <Button>
        <Link href="/new">
          <a>Aboutus</a>
        </Link>
    </Button>
</div>)}
export default NavBarr;
```

Comment: you have to add all pages at pages directory to get a route link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Next.js when a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.

I suggest you to read https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Comment: I have added both Navbar.tsx and App.tsx in the pages folder only. Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/r45pif

Comment: Please check the screenshot above, all the route files mentioned in App.tsx are in the pages folder

Comment: `<Link href="/new">` doesn't mach with `NewQuestion.tsx`.
Try to rename the file or the route eg. `new.tsx`

Comment: I have renamed <Link href="/new"> to <Link href="/NewQuestion"> but then what is the point of routing in this? In my app.tsx I have routed /new to NewQuestion

Comment: Have a check on this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link
You are probably gonna find everything you need.

Comment: Hey! Now I'm getting an error with the save button on newqyestion